# Module parse failed: Identifier '_templateObject' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Everything was working fine before, but one morning I started getting this error. I didn't change anything in the project, I didn't use a new version of Node.js.

I tried absolutely everything - tearing down Node.js completely and reinstalling it, but it didn't solve the problem. The funny thing is that everything works fine in the online IDE.

I know that it happens because of Emotion styled. If I'll remove css in js - everything works.

```
 ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
    info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\user\Downloads\zigi-ui-master\.env
    event - compiled client and server successfully in 631 ms (203 modules)
    wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
    event - compiled client and server successfully in 93 ms (204 modules)
    warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/fast-refresh#how-it-works
    wait  - compiling /...
    error - ./pages/index.jsx
    Module parse failed: Identifier '_templateObject' has already been declared (13:9)
    File was processed with these loaders:
     * ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-refresh-utils/dist/loader.js     
     * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
    You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
    |     return data;
    | }
    > function _templateObject() {
    |     var data = _tagged_template_literal([
    |         "\n  text-align: center;\n  justify-content: center;\n"
```

Comment: See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44113#issuecomment-1898503310

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this same issue today. I reported it to the Next.js team here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44113 However, I now realize that the problem was caused by the VS Code [Console Ninja extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.console-ninja), which works by hooking in to the compilation process.

I've filed a report with the Console Ninja folks here: https://github.com/wallabyjs/console-ninja/issues/59 In the meantime, I'd recommend disabling the extension while working with Next.js.

**Update:** Per the Console Ninja team's response, it looks like the issue actually happens any time Next.js sees an `eval` statement in the same module as multiple template literals. In my case that `eval` was injected by Console Ninja, but the problem isn't unique to that extension.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it today as well, updating the community =)

Answer (score 1):

After days of debugging I finally found that it was indeed **Console Ninja Extension** in **VS Code** that was causing this **error**. Just **disable it** and use normal console logs or you can also use **Turbo Console Log** Extension to write meaningful consoles. Good Luck !